# Showing that $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = 4x - 5$ is onto

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Hello attached is my attempt of the problem. I hope I did this correctly. Does this make sense? Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: In the last box, the software is probably expecting the answer "y."

Comment: You seem to be assuming what you need to prove.  (y+5)/4 in R needs a proof.  It is equivalent to what you are trying to prove.

Comment: @herbsteinberg.  That proof is trivial, thus unneeded in this context.

Comment: Right on.......

Comment: If the assignment is filling in squares you did it correctly.  The real issue (and I blame the assignment; not you) is to understand that "onto" means for evey $y \in R$ there is an $x$ so that $4x - 5 = y$.  And that the process of solving for $x= \frac{y+5}4$ tells us that there is such an $x$.  It is $\frac {y+5}4$.

Answer (score 1):

You can show it in two ways.

The first is your method, for every $y \in \mathbb{R}$ we can find $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $y=f(x)$ that is

$$x=\frac{y+5}{4}$$

The second is to observe that $f(x)$ is continuos and

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)=+\infty$$

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x)=-\infty$$

thus for IVT for each $y$ we can find $x$ such that $y=f(x)$.